# Sort by multiple fields in Lodash 2.x

Tags: javascript, sorting, lodash

Supposing this array:

```
var members = [
  {firstName: 'Michael', weight: 2}, 
  {firstName: 'Thierry', weight: 1}, 
  {firstName: 'Steph', weight: 3},
  {firstName: 'Jordan', weight: 3}, 
  {firstName: 'John', weight: 2}
];
```

I want to sort by weight and for each kind of weight, sorting by firstNames (a nested sort so).

Result would be:

```
[
  {firstName: 'Thierry', weight: 1}, 
  {firstName: 'John', weight: 2}, 
  {firstName: 'Michael', weight: 2}, 
  {firstName: 'Jordan', weight: 3}, 
  {firstName: 'Steph', weight: 3}
];
```

I achieve this quickly using [Lodash](https://lodash.com) 2.4.1:

```
return _.chain(members)
    .groupBy('weight')
    .pairs()
    .sortBy(function(e) {
        return e[0];
    })
    .map(function(e){
        return e[1];
    })
    .map(function(e){
        return _.sortBy(e, 'firstName')
    })
    .flatten()
    .value();
```

Is there a better way to achieve it using Lodash 2.4.1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can chain two sorts:

```
_(members).sortBy('firstName').sortBy('weight').value()
```

Comment: I'd mention this works because lodash's sortBy uses a stable sort

Comment: I don't know which answer I should vote for :) Each solution is elegant.

Comment: I was not aware about the stability of the sort.

Comment: You asked about a solution using lodash :-) however I would recommend using pure JS while you can, especially if you're gonna do a lot of these sorts: it's always faster and more performant

Answer (score 4):

It's even in plain Javascript very short.

```js
var members = [
    { firstName: 'Michael', weight: 2 },
    { firstName: 'Thierry', weight: 1 },
    { firstName: 'Steph', weight: 3 },
    { firstName: 'Jordan', weight: 3 },
    { firstName: 'John', weight: 2 }
];

members.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.weight - b.weight || a.firstName.localeCompare(b.firstName);
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(members, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: it's a very smart way

Answer (score 1):

Another variation of using lodash if you are using an older version of lodash

```
var members = [
{ firstName: 'Michael', weight: 2 },
{ firstName: 'Thierry', weight: 1 },
{ firstName: 'Steph', weight: 3 },
{ firstName: 'Jordan', weight: 3 },
{ firstName: 'John', weight: 2 }
```

];

var result = _.sortBy(members, ['firstname', 'weight'], ['asc', 'asc']);

console.log('result ', result);